# Fourier Series Coefficients Question

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I am working on a question and require some assistance. The question is:

> Let $c_0, c_n$ and $d_n$ be denoted as the following:
>   $$c_0 = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 e^x \> dx, \>\>\>\> c_n = \int_{-1}^1 e^x\cos(n\pi x) dx, \>\>\>\>\>\> d_n = \int_{-1}^1e^x\sin(n\pi x) dx$$
>   What is:
>   $$2c_0^2+\sum_{n=1}c_n^2+d_n^2$$

Now I know for the Full Fourier Series of $e^x$ these are the coefficients given. But if the coefficients are squared, it does not mean that the above will give the Fourier Series of $e^{2x}$? Am I supposed to brute force integrate these, or am I missing a trick here?

Comment: It is $\int_{-1}^1 |f(x)|^2dx$

Comment: @reuns I'm confused by how you got this. $c_n^2$ does not imply that we are squaring the integrand, so I'm kinda confused by this. Do you mean its the integral from $(-1,1)$ of the norm of the fourier series $e^x$ squared? If so, I'm still confused by how the above gets to the summation formula in my question

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem